# Problem with enclosing matrix multiplication with OpenMP, into a function

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I wrote basic program for matrix multiplication, and its works fine. But when i tried to put all my code inside function. The function begin to spit out from numbers. In code below, i have 2 readMatrix functions, each of which is hard coded to read its own file, after than i multiply them inside Main function, using OpenMP. Function "readMatrix3x3" is my attempt to put all this, inside one single function. But OpenMP part inside readMatrix3x3 is giving out wrong numbers. Please help me understand why my previously worked code, not working inside function.

```
#define MAX 3
int iMat1[MAX][MAX];
int iMat2[MAX][MAX];
int iResult[MAX][MAX];
int i, j, k;

void* readMatrix() {

    vector<vector<int>> v;
    ifstream ifs("matrix.txt");
    string tempstr;
    int tempint;
    char delimiter = ',';
    while (getline(ifs, tempstr)) {
        istringstream iss(tempstr);
        vector<int> tempv;
        while (iss >> tempint) {
            tempv.push_back(tempint);
            iss >> delimiter;
        }
        v.push_back(tempv);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            iMat1[i][j] = v[i][j];
    }
}

void* readMatrix2() {

    vector<vector<int>> v;
    ifstream ifs("matrix2.txt");
    string tempstr;
    int tempint;
    char delimiter = ',';

    while (getline(ifs, tempstr)) {
        istringstream iss(tempstr);
        vector<int> tempv;
        while (iss >> tempint) {
            tempv.push_back(tempint);
            iss >> delimiter;
        }
        v.push_back(tempv);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            iMat2[i][j] = v[i][j];
    }
}


void* readMatrix3x3(string mat1, string mat2) {
#define MAX 3
    int iMat1[MAX][MAX];
    int iMat2[MAX][MAX];
    int iResult[MAX][MAX];
    int i, j, k = 0;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    vector<vector<int>> vMat1;
    vector<vector<int>> vMat2;
    ifstream ifsMatrix1(mat1);
    ifstream ifsMatrix2(mat2);
    string tempstr;
    string tempstr2;
    int tempint;
    int tempint2;
    char delimiter = ',';
    while (getline(ifsMatrix1, tempstr)) {
        istringstream iss(tempstr);
        vector<int> tempv;
        while (iss >> tempint) {
            tempv.push_back(tempint);
            iss >> delimiter;
        }
        vMat1.push_back(tempv);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            iMat1[i][j] = vMat1[i][j];
    }
    while (getline(ifsMatrix2, tempstr2)) {
        istringstream iss(tempstr2);
        vector<int> tempv2;
        while (iss >> tempint2) {
            tempv2.push_back(tempint2);
            iss >> delimiter;
        }
        vMat2.push_back(tempv2);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            iMat2[i][j] = vMat2[i][j];
    }

#pragma omp parallel for shared(iMat1, iMat2, iResult) private(i, j, k)

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
#pragma omp critical
                iResult[i][j] += iMat1[i][k] * iMat2[k][j];
        }
    }
    cout << "Results: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            cout << iResult[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main() {

readMatrix();
readMatrix2();

#pragma omp parallel for shared(iMat1, iMat2, iResult) private(i, j, k)

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            for (k = 0; k < MAX; k++)
                iResult[i][j] += iMat1[i][k] * iMat2[k][j];
        }
    }

    cout << "Results: " << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
                cout << iResult[i][j] << " ";
            cout << endl;
        }

        readMatrix3x3("matrix.txt", "matrix2.txt");


}
```

Output:

```
Results: 
119 49 98 
105 51 70 
59 28 41

Results: 
1877935468 2686789 2686830 
2686689 2686783 2686829 
69 2686612 1877747306
```

Comment: Unless it is for an exercise, that use of OpenMP is completely inappropriate. The matrices are very small. The parallelized loop is just 3*3*3=729 multiplications. This takes less than 1 microsecond to execute, far less than the time needed to spawn a thread.

Comment: @prapin Maybe the dimensions are small so that you can have readable output.

Comment: Is it working properly if you remove openmp directives?

Comment: @prapin Yes it is for exercise for my Uni.

Comment: Lack of formatting, some typos. And question is too broad. It's hard to give one particular answer to that one. Such questions are better fit in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

1. Instead of `private(i,j,k)`, declare the loop variables in the loop header.
2. You have `i,j,k` loops; only the outer one will be OMP parallel. Add `collapse(2)` to the `parallel for` pragma.
3. Remove the `critical` because there is no data conflict: each `i,j` will be done by a separate thread.
4. Do you ever initialize `iResult`? That's probably your actual problem.
5. Bonus comment: the mix of `std::vector` and array notation is very ugly. Try not to use the `[]` stuff because it doesn't scale. Also: please no global variables.

Comment: Thx you very much, the problem was un-initialized iResult, indeed. But it did work without initialization outside of function.... well never let logic lead your way when you learn new language from a scratch, i guess.  And thx for you other suggestions, too!